# Javascript - Modify array value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a javascript array that looks like this..

```
0: {color: "green", shape: "round"}
1: {color: "red", shape: "square"}
3: {color: "blue", shape: "flat"}
```

I am trying to change just the value of shape like this..

```
myarray[1] = {shape: "oblong"};
```

But this is removing the color value as well, how can I do this and keep the other values?

Comment: This is suspicious. Where is the the element with 2nd index

Comment: @brk: I guess OP might have added the content manually and not by copying actual data.

Comment: Your attempt is replacing the index with an object, it is not working with the object.

Answer (score 9):

That's because you are setting the array value and not property `shape` of the underlying Object:

```
 myarray[1].shape =  "oblong";
```

Comment: when I grow up I want to get 8 upvotes in a simple answer like that. :D

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way to modify the object is to use `Object.assign` function, so it would look like this:

```
myarray[1] = Object.assign(myarray[1], {shape: "oblong"});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = {
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
}
console.log("before test: ",arr["age"]);
arr["age"] = 70;
console.log("after test: ",arr["age"]);
```

Comment: Code Dropping is frowned upon ..  You should EXPLAIN the answer and WHY it answers the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Your array has several objects in it. Each element is an object containing 2 properties (color and shape).

If you do

```
myarray[1] = {shape: "oblong"};
```

you're atributing a new object to index 1 of myarray, thus what's left is the new object that has only one propery (shape).

if you do instead

```
myarray[1].shape = "oblong";
```

the object in myarray[1] will be:

```
color: "red", shape: "oblong"}
```